# php download file: header()

Tags: php, header

I need some eduction please.
At the end of each month, I want to download some data from my webserver to my local PC.
So, I've written a little script for that, which selects the data from the DB.
Next, I want to download it.
I've tried this:

```
$file=$month . '.txt';
$handle=fopen($file, "w");
header("Content-Type: application/text");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment, filename=" . $month . '.txt');
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
    {
    $writestring = $row['data_I_want'] . "\r\n";
    fwrite($handle, $writestring);
    }
fclose($handle);
```

If I run this, then the file is created, but my file doesn't contain the data that I want. Instead I get a dump from the HTML-file in my browser..
What am I doing wrong..
Thanks,
Xpoes

Comment: use the header part after the while loop.

Comment: @GauravVashishtha : What will be difference then???Headers must be sent before any output!

Comment: You are writing text into file on webserver.Please show us code where you send it to broswer.

Comment: I've put it before, and when that didn't work after fclose, both not with the desired result..

Comment: ok, it goes like this:
a simple php-file with 2 options, and HTML at the top and bottom of it.

          if (!isset($_POST['data_I_want'])) {
            require('data_I_wantform.inc');
          }

          else {
            require('process_data_I_want.inc');
          }

The process file, processes the request and says 'echo "Done!"' when finished.

Answer (score 3):

Below script will help you download the file created

```
//Below is where you create particular month's text file
$file=$month . '.txt';
$handle=fopen($file, "w");
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)){
    $writestring = $row['data_I_want'] . "\r\n";
    fwrite($handle, $writestring);
}
fclose($handle);
//Now the file is ready with data from database

//Add below to download the text file created
$filename = $file; //name of the file
$filepath = $file; //location of the file. I have put $file since your file is create on the same folder where this script is
header("Cache-control: private");
header("Content-type: application/force-download");
header("Content-transfer-encoding: binary\n");
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($filepath));
readfile($filepath);
exit;
```

Comment: Yes, that works. However, I still get a dump of the HTML of the page in which the whole thing is embedded. 
I guess I will have to write it to a new/empty file then.
But thanks anyway, all comments/answers are much appreciated!

Comment: Yes. This download script should be a separate file. It should not print out anything.

Answer (score 0):

Your current code does not output a file, it just sends headers.

in order for your script to work add the following code after your `fclose` statement.

```
 $data = file_get_contents($file);
 echo $data;
```