# Creating CSV file from PHP, no line feed

Tags: php, file, csv

I am trying to create a CSV file from my web page and am having issue with line feeds/carraige returns.

I am building up the CSV string via Javascript and then adding '\u000A' + "\u000D" to the end of each line.

I then pass my CSV sting to a PHP program via AJAX. My PHP logic to create the file is: -

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="effortTool.csv"');
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($content));
```

When I view the file it does not contain any line feeds/carraige retuns.

If I output the CSV string as an "alert", I can see it is formatting corerctly. This tells me that the line feeds characters are being added but are being lost when downloaded as a file.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Martin

Comment: Any reason why you are building the csv with javascript and not php?

Comment: The web application is written usign HTML/Javascript. Would it make a difference as to which language I choose?

Answer (score 3):

Use following code to generate `CSV` file:-

```
ob_clean();
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header( "Content-disposition: filename=effortTool.csv");
header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($content));
print $content;
exit;
```

This was working for me, hope it'll work for you too.

Answer (score 1):

You put the file content on the meta data of type Content-Length, this is wrong.

Try this: [php download file: header()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17037296/php-download-file-header)

Comment: That gave me the same issue, however, I concatenated '\r\n' . "boohoo" to my CSV content and the file was created correctly. So therefore, I will pass the file content as an array to the PHP and get PHP to add the new line stuff.